# What does cd $BAR do?

Tags: linux

Anyone know what is this Linux command?

```
cd $BAR
```

I have searched it in google. Cant find a perfect example where i can comprehend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It replaces `$BAR` with the value of the variable `$BAR` and runs `cd` on it (change directory). If there is nothing in `$BAR`, it runs plain `cd` which takes you to the `$HOME` directory.

Try setting `$BAR`:

```
BAR=/ ; cd $BAR ; pwd
```

Comment: Thanks, its quite simple. Thanks for showing it to me clearly.

Answer (score 2):

`echo $BAR`

This will tell you what's set. `$BAR` is a variable.

Comment: it doesnt display anything. or it displays a whitespace

Comment: Because your variable is empty.